# ios not rendering button attributes

Tags: html, css

I have a button that renders correctly on windows, and mobile simulations. However, on my iPhone, the button color, and position attributes are incorrect. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

html:

```
<button class="more-projects-button" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='Projects.html';">More Projects</button>
```

css:

```
.more-projects-button {
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Thanks for looking at my code, as I'm new to web development

Answer (score -1):

The commented above is correct.
You can use "-webkit-" for other web browser and "-moz-" for Firefox.

Example :

```html
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);

-webkit-background-color: red;
-moz-background-color: red;
background-color: red;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=transform - https://caniuse.com/?search=background-color